# corner image, footer. bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help. I need to make adaptive image in footer and to put the picture in right corner. Size of pic is: 150x150 px.

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-xs-center"> TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
    text text text<br>
    <a href="</a> </p>
  </div>
</footer>

footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

I ask you to help me, with some code. With my old code - was bad responsive.On gadgets with  600 x 1024 display - footer text is superimposed on the image.

Comment: <footer>
<div class="container">
<p class="text-xs-center"> TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
text text text<br>
<a href="</a> </p>
</div>
</footer>

footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know the if "text-right" is a really bootstrap class... However, I think that this layout would work.

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-xs-center"> TEXT TEXT TEXT<br>
    text text text<br>
    <a href=""></a> </p>
    <p class="text-right"><img scr="YOUR IMAGE PATH HERE" /></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! Text-right is not a bootstrap class. hmm, with bootstrap div class=container  my text is displayed at the top of footer. It is possible to make text at the middle of footer? If it is possible I will paste here my old code: .footer_img {
background-image: url(/theme/adres/p1.png); 
background-position: 100% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 150px;
}

.footertext {
color:white;
display:table;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
height:100%;
}

.footertext p {
margin:0;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 0):

Class "pull-right" should be mentioned in img tag. Further, bootstrap col classes can be used to place text and image side by side.
The code is below:

HTML

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <p class="text-xs-center text-danger"> TEXT TEXT TEXT<br> text text text<br>
        <a href="">Link</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150" alt="image" class="pull-right" /></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you so much! My footers width is - 100 %. Unfortunately, the picture remains somewhere in the middle. With text the same problem. https://postimg.org/image/odite2m6d/

Comment: It works the same in Codepen as well  - (http://codepen.io/priyankamalviya/pen/yMBRda) .Could you please check if the div enclosing footer has some width issues? Another tip - try adding max-width: 90% to .container class

Comment: no, there is no such. Thanks for help, but text not at the middle. And pic is not at the right corner. I do everything according to your instructions.